# Multidatabase connection using php laravel framework

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'patnership.zvss_new_transaction' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `zvss_new_transaction` where `outletName` = uchumi and `transactionDate` = 2017-02-13 limit 1)

I keep getting that error when i try and implement multidatabase connection using laravel and it keeps connecting to the default database even after specifying the other datbases in the environment and database files. I have also added the connection on my model and keep on hitting a wall...assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Attached below are the concerned code files

**database.php**

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Database Connection Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
| to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
| you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
|
*/

'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Database Connections
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
| Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
| supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
|
|
| All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
| so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
| choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
|
*/

'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'patnership'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'zippoco'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'mysql2' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'hostname'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'databasename'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'username'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Migration Repository Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
| your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
| the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
|
*/

'migrations' => 'migrations',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Redis Databases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
| provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
| such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
|
*/

'redis' => [

    'client' => 'predis',

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],

],

];
```

**model:Home.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Home extends Model
{
    //

    protected $connection = 'mysql2';

    protected $table='zvss_new_transaction';
}
```

**Controller:HomeController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Home;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //


        $data=Home::where('outletName', '=', "uchumi")
            ->where('transactionDate', '=','2017-02-13')
            ->first();

        return view('home',compact('data'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem with following steps

1.In your .env,add another database connection  params  e.g

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=database1
DB_USERNAME=username1
DB_PASSWORD=password1
DB_HOST=host1

DB_EXT_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_EXT_DATABASE=database2
DB_EXT_USERNAME=username2
DB_EXT_PASSWORD=password2
DB_EXT_HOST=host2
```

The first one is the usual connection,and the second one is the external database connection.

2.In your config/database.php under connection,add the fowllowing

```
     'mysql2' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_EXT_HOST', 'host2'),
        'database'  => env('DB_EXT_DATABASE', 'database2'),
        'username'  => env('DB_EXT_USERNAME', 'username2'),
        'password'  => env('DB_EXT_PASSWORD', 'password2'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
    //Now we have established the connection,
```

3.In your controller,

```
 $someModel = new Models();

    $someModel->setConnection('mysql2');
    $something = $someModel->get();


     foreach($something as $mod){
      $model=new Models();
      $model->id=$mod->id;
      $model->make_id=$mod->make_id;
      $model->make=$mod->make;
      $model->model=$mod->model;
      $model->save();

     }
```

This is used whenever you want to connect to the external database. Intailize the model ,and give it the connection you want to use and then the rest remains the same.